# Pointers and recursive functions in C

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

I have created a list with numbers. For example:

```
-3 4 -2 -1 4 5
```

The products of two continuous nodes are `-14 -8 2 -4 21`. I want to check if the product of two nodes is always bigger than the product of the following ones. I used a recursive function and in this example the treaty is unsuccessful because `2>-4`.

I also want to print a message showing the first node which causes the problem. In this case is -1 which is the 4th node. How will I return a pointer showing the wrong node? See the questionmarks :)

```
struct node* findNode(struct node *junc) {
    //Success
    if(junc->link->link==NULL){
      printf("SUCCESS");
      return NULL;
    }
    //Failure        
    if (((junc->content)*(junc->link->content))>=((junc->link->content)*(junc->link->link->content))) {
      printf("FAIL.");
      printf("\nFAIL because of numbers:%d %d.",junc->link->content,junc->link->link->content);
      return junc;                              
    }           
    return(findNode(junc->link));
}
```

Comment: int main()
{
            if(ptr!=NULL) 
            {
                printf("\nFail is cause by the %dth node.", ?????????);
            }       
            else           
              printf("\n%d",ptr);

Comment: Be careful using a recursive function, if the list is big enough you may get a **Stack Overflow**

Comment: @Hmmas- Add the comment in your code by editing it.

Comment: No, `-3 * 4` is not `-14`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check if the product of two nodes is always bigger than the product of the following ones.

I think you had your code the wrong way around, i.e. you had >= but it should be <= according to your description.

The code below will return a pointer to the wrong node (i.e. the first of the two numbers whose product is less than or equal to the product of the next two numbers)

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    int content;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* findNode(struct node* node) {
    if(node->next->next == 0){
      printf("SUCCESS");
      return 0;
    }

    if ((node->content * node->next->content) <= (node->next->content * node->next->next->content)) {
      printf("FAIL because of numbers: %d and %d", node->next->content, node->next->next->content);
      return node;                              
    }   

    return(findNode(node->next));
}

int main() {
    struct node node1 = {5, 0};
    struct node node2 = {4, &node1};
    struct node node3 = {-1, &node2};
    struct node node4 = {-2, &node3};
    struct node node5 = {4, &node4};
    struct node node6 = {-3, &node5};

    struct node* res = findNode(&node6);

    if (res != 0) {
        // res is a pointer to the wrong node
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your time.However,i m not supposed to store as a parameter the number of the elements of the list.I can give as many numbers  i like.I m supposed to get a pointer from the recursion to find which node causes the failure of my treaty

Comment: @Hmmas this is just an example - you can modify it to get the nodes however you like rather than creating the variables.